# Opacity transition on a div is randomly "blocky"

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML structure for a tiled page layout. The idea is, when the user hovers over an image tile it becomes slightly transparent (giving the effect of it darkening with the black background behind) and some previously hidden text is then displayed.

```
<div class="tileContainer">
    <a class="tileLink" href="/contact">
        <section class="tile">    
            <img src="/images/contact-s.jpg" srcset="/images/contact-m.jpg 600w, /images/contact-l.jpg 1000w, /images/contact-xl.jpg 1920w" alt="contact">
            <h1>Contact</h1>
            <p class="hidden">Temporary hover text</p>
        </section> 
    </a>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.tileLink{
    display: block;
    float: left;
}

.tileLink:hover .tile img, .tileLink:focus .tile img{
    opacity: 0.65;
}

.tileLink:hover p, .tileLink:focus p{
    display: inline;
}
```

The problem is, sometimes (and this doesn't happen every time), when you hover a tile the opacity comes in very blocky. Initially it will go like this:

[image]

Before the opacity "jumps" to the rest of the tile and fills the rest with the darker background.

I don't even know what to google for this, let alone begin investigating the cause. The url to view this happening is: http://streeten-new.streeten.co.uk/

Any help much appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

The image has a transition:

```
.navTiles .tile img{
    -o-transition: 0.4s;
    -ms-transition: 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: 0.4s;
    -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
    transition: 0.4s;
}
```

When I remove this, the opacity works perfectly... but ideally I'd like to use it so the opacity fades in and out.

Comment: Just add `opacity: 1` to your `img` with transition as `transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;` and you're good to go.   The actualy problem is that, `transition ` is not working for opacity as it does have its initial value to render to its `:hover` state i.e. why. So when you set `Opacity: 1` with `transition` the it has `1` as initial to render it to `0.65` on `:hover`.

Comment: I don't expierence the blocky effect, even after 10 times of reloading the page and trying again. Isn't it a browser bug, related to your graphical card?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is funny, I think it is a Chrome render bug. I don't know why it behaves that way but i manage to get a workaround using an initial `opacity` of `.999` on the `.title img` element.

```
.navTiles .tile img {
    opacity: .999;

    -o-transition: 0.4s;
    -ms-transition: 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: 0.4s;
    -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
    transition: 0.4s;
}
```

It will have an opacity but it will be very subtle to notice.

Try it and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

While probably a chrome bug You could try:

You are giving the `opacity`on hover to the image... Insteed, just wrap your `<img>` into a `div`and give the opacity to this container and not to the image